Imprimir todos los elementos iguales de varias sublistas en Python
Mi duda es bastante basica. Tengo una lista de habitaciones de hotel, cada habitación siendo su lista propia, y al final de cada una aclara si dicha habitación esta ocupada, reservada o libre.
Quiero recorrer todos los elementos de la lista, y luego imprimir solamente los números de las habitaciones que están "libres", pero no me funciona.
habitaciones = [
[1, "individual", 80000, "ocupado"],
[2, "individual", 80000, "ocupado"],
[3, "individual", 80000, "libre"],
[4, "doble", 100000, "reservado"],
[5, "doble", 100000, "ocupado"],
[6, "doble", 100000, "libre"],
[7, "suite", 130000, "libre"],
[8, "suite", 130000, "reservado"]
]

def canthabitaciones (lista):

    for i in range (len(habitaciones)) :
        if  len(habitaciones[3])=="libre":
            print ("La habitacion", len(habitaciones[0]),"Esta disponible" )
        else:
            print ("invalido")   


Bienvenido. Qué intentaste? Tienes un ejemplo del resultado esperado?

Yo quiero que la funcion recorra mi lista y luego me imprima solo las habitaciones que estan categorizadas como "libres" fijandose en la posicion [3] de cada sublista.  Quiero que me imprima algo asi como "La habitacion", numero de la habitacion,"esta disponible" Y repita lo mismo con las otras que estan libres

El principal problema lo tienes en el condicional:
if  len(habitaciones[3])=="libre":

len() retorna el número de items del iterable, en tu caso la lista habitaciones, por lo que retornará siempre 8 en tu ejemplo. Esto hace que la comparación sea en todas las iteraciones:
if 8 == "libre":

lo cual es obviamente siempre falso.
Debes usar el índice suministrado por el for-range en cada iteración  para indizar sobre cada sublista y aplicar sobre un segundo indizado para obtener el cuarto item:
if  habitaciones[i][3]=="libre":

Dado que tu función espera recibir como parámetro la lista con las habitaciones, deberías usar el argumento y no la variable global como ocurre ahora.
def canthabitaciones(lista_habitaciones):
    for i in range (len(lista_habitaciones)):
        if  lista_habitaciones[i][3]=="libre":
            print ("La habitación", lista_habitaciones[i][0], "está disponible" )
        else:
            print("inválido")

canthabitaciones(habitaciones)

No obstante, usar un for + range + len + indizado para simplemente iterar y obtener los items de un iterable es ineficiente. En estos casos es recomendable iterar sobre la lista directamente con un for in, que además de ser más eficiente es más legible:
for habitacion in lista_habitaciones:
    if habitacion[3] == "libre":

o incluso puedes desempaquetar cada sublista en el mismo for:
for num, tipo, precio, estado in lista_habitaciones:
    if estado == "libre":

aunque por lo general las variables no usadas se denotan con un guion bajo:
for num, _, _, estado in lista_habitaciones:

o directamente:
for num, *_, estado in lista_habitaciones:

Quedando algo así:
def canthabitaciones(lista_habitaciones):
    for num, *_, estado in lista_habitaciones:
        if estado == "libre":
            print(f"La habitación {num} está disponible")  


Maestro, si pudiera daría tres +1.

En Python, como en varios otros lenguajes interpretados, los arreglos de datos se pueden recorrer directamente. Entonces, a menos que necesites esa i para otro cálculo, no es necesario el generador range().
El principal error es que en esta línea if len(habitaciones[3])=="libre"  estás comparando un entero con una cadena, lo cual siempre será False, por lo que el resultado siempre será print(invalido)
Una mejora de tu algoritmo es que se puede hacer que la función no imprima los datos, si no que genere otra lista con los datos filtrados. O sea, los que si cumplen las condiciones.
NOTA - El uso de los métodos .lower() es para comparar minúsculas con minúsculas, si observas, intencionalmente coloco 'Libre', con la L mayúscula y aún así funciona.
def filtrar(lista, filtro=None):
    if not filtro:
        return lista
    res = []
    for elem in lista:
        if elem[3].lower() == filtro.lower():
            res.append(elem)
    return res
    
habitaciones = [
[1, "individual", 80000, "ocupado"],
[2, "individual", 80000, "ocupado"],
[3, "individual", 80000, "libre"],
[4, "doble", 100000, "reservado"],
[5, "doble", 100000, "ocupado"],
[6, "doble", 100000, "libre"],
[7, "suite", 130000, "libre"],
[8, "suite", 130000, "reservado"]
]

estado = 'Libre'

result = filtrar(habitaciones, estado)
for elem in result:
    print(f"Habitación {elem[0]} ({elem[1]} ${elem[2]}) está {elem[3]}")
print("Cantidad de habitaciones:", len(result))

La salida de lo anterior será:
Habitación 3 (individual $80000) está libre
Habitación 6 (doble $100000) está libre
Habitación 7 (suite $130000) está libre
Cantidad de habitaciones: 3

Puedes probar cambiar la variable estado a 'Ocupado' u otra cosa; o incluso colocar un input para que entres por consola el estado.
